# Integrating stimulsoft to MVC4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, stimulsoft

I'm trying to integrate stimulsoft designer in my web application (MVC4, Razor 2 and Entity Framework 4) but I have encountred some problems.

I have integrated the dlls and the assemblies, but I have this error :

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Source Error: @Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(new StiMvcViewerOptions() {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by making following changes in the Web.Config file:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```